# Agora RTM login failed

Tags: swift, agora.io, github-issues, rtm, agora-implementation

connection changed to connected connecting, because login
login failed: AgoraRtmLoginErrorCode
connection changed to connected disconnected, because loginFailure

```
func setupRTM() {
        self.agoraRTM = AgoraRtmKit(
            appId: "<#Agora App Id#>",
            delegate: self
        )
        print("logging in as \(UIDevice.current.name)")
        self.agoraRTM.login(
            byToken: nil, user: UIDevice.current.name,
            completion: self.rtmLoginCallback
        )
    }

    func rtmLoginCallback(_ err: AgoraRtmLoginErrorCode) {
        if err != .ok {
            print("login failed: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("login success")
            self.createAndJoin(channel: self.lobbyChannelName) { channel in
                self.lobbyChannel = channel
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an RTM token to log in.
`self.agoraRTM.login(byToken: nil)`, the token should not be nil.

Hope this link may help you:
https://docs.agora.io/en/signaling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=ios#1-set-your-signing-and-team

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your `UIDevice.current.name` holds characters that are not allowed by default as the username for RTM. I tend to use [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) converted to a string, and then pass the `UIDevice.current.name` as a message telling everyone in the channel that it's my username. Especially as many people simply have "iPhone" as their device name, which would of course not be unique.

Permitted characters are mentioned in the API Ref [here](https://api-ref.agora.io/en/signaling-sdk/ios/1.x/Classes/AgoraRtmKit.html#//api/name/loginByToken:user:completion:).

If that doesn't fix it, check the value of [AgoraRtmLoginErrorCode](https://api-ref.agora.io/en/signaling-sdk/ios/1.x/Constants/AgoraRtmLoginErrorCode.html). If it's `.invalidArgument`, then it will likely be the username that's being used.